# Showing that a subgroup of two normal abelian subgroups is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with two normal, abelian subgroups, $A$ and $B$. $|A|$ and $|B|$ are coprimes. $A\cap B = \{e\}$.

I'm to show that $AB = \{xy\mid x\in A,y\in B\}$ is an abelian group. I tried doing some calculating it, but got nowhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x\in A,y\in B$ be arbitrary. Then since $A$ is normal and $y\in G$ we have that $yx^{-1}y^{-1}\in A$ since $A$ is closed under conjugation by elements in $G$ and therefore $x(yx^{-1}y^{-1})\in A$. A similar argument shows that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in B$. But $A\cap B=\{e\}$ and therefore $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=e$. I leave it to you to conclude.